# C++ Multi-Assign Python feature

Tags: c++, syntax

I am trying to learn C++. While experimenting, I typed in the following code, not expecting it to work, but hoping it would:

```
int one = 1, two = 2;
one, two = two, one;

cout << "one = " << one << "\n";
cout << "two = " << two << "\n";
```

I was encouraged by the fact that the compiler didn't complain, because this is one of the main features that I love about python that most every programming language I've ever learned does not match - the ability to evaluate multiple expressions before assigning the results WITHOUT using a temporary variable. However, I found when I ran it that this code seems to be ineffectual.

After playing around a bit, I discovered that the variable `two` is actually being set - so, if I ran this code:

```
one, two = 3, 4;
```

`two` would be equal to 3, but `one` would be unchanged. And so my question is, what exactly is the compiler doing in this statement? I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Thanks,
Brandon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `=` operator has higher precedence than `,` thus both lines below are equivalent:

```
(one), (two = 3), (4);
one, two = 3, 4;
```

Second, the comma operator is a way to group multiple statements, but only express the value of the last one, so:

```
int a, b;
a = (b = 5, b*b);
cout << a << '\n';
```

Would print 25. Hope to have enlightened you on what the compiler was doing.

Comment: I'm going to select this as the answer because it explains what's actually going on in that line, rather than describing alternatives. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

Multi-assignment python style is not supported in C++, the comma operator does not do what you intend: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

If you were assigning the same value to both `one` and `two` then you could do

```
one = two = 3;
```

but in your case you are not so they must be on separate lines:

```
one = 3;
two = 4;
```

if you wanted to swap the values then you must use a temporary third variable:

```
int temp = one;
one = two;
two = temp;
```

If we consider the following:

```
one, two = 3, 4;
```

the simple case is `3 ,4;` here the 4 will be discarded so only 3 will remain, you then have

```
one, two = 3;
```

Now you have the assignment operator `=` which has higher precedence than the `,` operator so irrespective of what happens with `one, two` the `two = 3;` is evaluated first before `one, two` resulting in:

```
two = 3;
```

Comment: Or you could use `std::swap` to swap the values. :-)

Comment: @BoPersson true, but I wanted to keep it simple ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm going to accept the other one, however, because it answers the question that I asked, rather than suggesting alternatives. Thanks especially for the Wikipedia article - it helps give more technical details that the selected answer does not.

Comment: @aboveyou00 no problem, python is a great language, I wish more languages were as expressive, compact and fun to code as python

Answer (score 4):

In C++11 there is [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

Example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(1, 2);
    std::cout << a << ", " << b;
}
```

Output: `1, 2`. `std::tie()` creates tuple of references - and `std::tuple` has overload for `operator=()`.

I know it's not same syntax as the one used in Python, but it's functionally the same and you may want to use it.